# How to MapRoute to one level up

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, maproute

How do I route this directory:

```
mywebsite/Views/Reports/Page.aspx
```

To this directory?

```
mywebsite/Reports/Page.aspx
```

The page must be a wild card, so something like this:

```
mywebsite/Views/Reports/*
```

To something like this:

```
mywebsite/Reports/*
```

Here is what I got:

```
            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "Reports",
                url: "Views/Reports/*",
                defaults: new { controller = "Reports"}
            );
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure whether I am getting your question completly, you can try this

```
        routes.MapRoute(
            "Test",
            "{upperDirectory}/{controller}/{action}",
            new { controller = "Reports", action="YourAction" },
        );
```

In this, your URL must have one value for variable upperDirectory.

Comment: This is better :
 
   routes.MapRoute(
        "Test",
        "Views/{controller}/{action}.aspx",
        new { controller = "Reports", action="Page" }
    );

Comment: Yes you are right, but I thought in case the one level up directory is not just Views.